# Check MySQL column contents inserting into based on if statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, curl

```
        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$opw,$odb);  //database login details
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())                                             //if you cannot access the database
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();         //useful error message
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PetLoc");

        if (!$result) { // add this check.
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
             if($row['Location'] == 'inside')
             {
               $sql = ("INSERT INTO PetLoc (Location) VALUES ('outside')");
               sendText("outside");
             }
             else
             {
                $sql =("INSERT INTO PetLoc (Location) VALUES ('inside')");
               sendText("inside");
             }
        }

    function sendText($petLoc) {  
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "smsserver");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $data = array(
             'mphone' => 'phoneno',
             'smstext' => 'Your pet walked through the door flap, it was last seen '.$petLoc.'.',
             'username' => 'uname'
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo "Output".$output ;

    }
mysqli_close($con);
```

This code is checking the contents of the the 'Location' column in my sql server if the contents are 'inside' it is supposed to change it to 'outside' and vice-versa. It is then sending the string 'outside/inside' to the sendText method which will utilise the response within a text message.

The issue is that no data is being changed within the server, I am getting no errors on connection, so it connects fine, yet is unable to insert into the db.

On running this PHP file I get no feedback other than OutputReturnCode 1 - but this is from curl implementation telling me the text was not sent.

Any help is appreciated,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is that no data is being changed within the server, I am getting no errors on connection, so it connects fine, yet is unable to insert into the db.

That's because there's no `mysqli_query()` in your code.

**Solution**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     if($row['Location'] == 'inside')
     {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO PetLoc (Location) VALUES ('outside')";
       mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       sendText("outside");
     }
     else
     {
        $sql =("INSERT INTO PetLoc (Location) VALUES ('inside')");
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       sendText("inside");
     }
}
```